# How to scale my textures to be consistent with each other

Tags: texturing, transforms

I have made a custom wood texture and have applied it to two objects, a countertop and a drawer:

[image]

The texture has affected the countertop nicely. However, the drawer has scaled the entire texture down. How do I prevent this from happening to ensure the scale of the texture is being applied consistently across objects of different size?

Here is my node tree:

[image]

Comment: Please show us your node-tree.. everything depends on what texture-space you're in..

Comment: Node tree added.

Comment: select all your objects, ctrl+A, apply scale.